# Django + Stripe (Orders and Items)

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Please help me to find an error in my code

I have a Django + Stripe project that has to process single item purchase and order purchase at the same time

With single items it works perfectly and I get redirected to Stripe form once I click on Buy button but I get

```
> Not Found: /order_checkout/1/ [04/Jan/2024 15:47:47] "GET
> /order_checkout/1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2953
```

for order purchase

Why?

this is my views.py

```
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .models import Item, Order, OrderItem

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


class ProductLandingPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'landing.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        item_id = self.kwargs["item_id"]
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=item_id)
        context['item'] = item
        context.update({
        "STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY": settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    })
        return context



class CreateCheckoutSessionOrderView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order_id = self.kwargs["order_id"]
        DOMAIN: str = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
        order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
        session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[
            {
                'price_data': {
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'unit_amount': order.get_total_cost() * 100,
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': order.__str__,
                    },
                },
                'quantity': 1,
            },
        ],
        payment_intent_data={
            'metadata': {
                'order_id': order.id,
            },
        },
        mode='payment',
        success_url=DOMAIN + '/success/',
        cancel_url=DOMAIN + '/cancel/',
    )
        return JsonResponse({'id': session.id})


class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        item_id = self.kwargs["item_id"]
        DOMAIN: str = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
        item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
        session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[
            {
                'price_data': {
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'unit_amount': item.price * 100,
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': item.name,
                    },
                },
                'quantity': 1,
            },
        ],
        payment_intent_data={
            'metadata': {
                'item_id': item.id,
            },
        },
        mode='payment',
        success_url=DOMAIN + '/success/',
        cancel_url=DOMAIN + '/cancel/',
    )
        return JsonResponse({'id': session.id})




class SuccessView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "success.html"


class CancelView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "cancel.html"


class OrderView(TemplateView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'order.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        order_id = self.kwargs["order_id"]
        order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
        context['order'] = order
        context.update({
        "STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY": settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
        'name': order.__str__(),
        'items': order.items,
        'total': order.get_total_cost()

    })
        return context
```

This is models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def display_price(self):
        return "{0:.2f}".format(self.price)


class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='OrderItem')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Order {self.id} | {self.created_at.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")}'

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.price for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

urls.py

```
from api.views import CancelView, SuccessView, CreateCheckoutSessionView, ProductLandingPageView, OrderView, CreateCheckoutSessionOrderView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('order_checkout/<int:order_id>', CreateCheckoutSessionOrderView.as_view(), name='order_checkout'),
path('order/<int:order_id>', OrderView.as_view(), name='order'),
path('item/<int:item_id>', ProductLandingPageView.as_view(), name='item'),
path('buy/<int:item_id>', CreateCheckoutSessionView.as_view(), name='buy'),
path('cancel/', CancelView.as_view(), name='cancel'),
path('success/', SuccessView.as_view(), name='success'),
]
```

and the template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Order purchase
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="description">
        <h3>{{ name }}</h3>
        <div class="order-info">

        <h5> Total cost {{ total }} USD.</h5>
    </div>
    <button id="buy-button" data-order-id="{{ order.id }}">Buy</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('buy-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var orderId = this.getAttribute('data-order-id');
  var stripe = Stripe("{{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}");
  fetch('/order_checkout/' + orderId)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (session) {
      return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Ошибка:', error);
    });
});
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "Order purchase" in your question exactly? Are you seeing the error on Stripe Checkout Page or in your own code??

My assumption is in your own code, you should add more logging in your code that runs when you make a fetch request to `/order_checkout` path. It seems like something in your logic is failing when you're attempting to create a checkout session and returning a 404 instead.

You should also be able to check your Stripe logs to see if there were any API errors. https://support.stripe.com/questions/finding-the-id-for-an-api-request

Comment: Issue solved by editing the stripe form in template. Thanks